# How do I find $g$ given $g^r \bmod p$

Tags: diffie-hellman

How can $g$ be derived from $c = g^r \bmod p$ ?

$g$ and $r$ are not known, but $c$ and $p$ is. And oracle can provide many $c$ but the $r$ and $p$ is always random.

I think this is somewhat related to Decisional Diffie Hellman but I am not sure where to go from there, as the $p$ is always random.

Comment: There are many $g,r$ pairs, as is usually the case when you have more unknowns than equations to constrain them.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I believe that the scenario is "suppose we are given a large number of $c, p$ pairs (each pair corresponding to a random unknown $r$); how can we rederive the common $g$?

Comment: Assuming that the scenario I proposed is correct, I have these questions: a) are the $p$ values preconditioned to be prime, or are they arbitrary random values, and b) how large is $g$ anyways?  If $g$ isn't too large (e.g. 100-200 bits), and if composite $p$ values are allowed, then it looks possible (given a long enough list); if $g$ is large (e.g. 2048 bits) and all the $p$'s are prime, this looks to be infeasible...

Comment: Is $p$ fixed for all pairs or is a new $p$ used each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

If we assume many pairs $(c_i,p_i)$, and all the $p_i$ are primes (because  often the letter $p$ is used when talking about primes, and you relate to the DLOG problem in your question where the modulus is also prime), then we can use this method:

We ignore all the $c_i$. For every $p_i$ we find one generator $g_i$ of the entire group. And then we use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find $g$, which fullfills $g = g_i \mod p_i$ for every $p_i$. Now $g$ is a generator for every subgroup, and therefore for every $p_i$ there exists some $r_i$, s.t. $c_i = g^{r_i}$. This has nothing to do with the DLOG problem, it is just finding a generator for several groups.

---

But if we assume any random $p_i$, then we also need a closes look at the numbers, and we need to consider all the $c_i$ as well:

- First, we need to check which $c_i$ are not coprime to their respective $p_i$. If $ggt(c_i,p_i) = a$, then we already know that $a$ is a prime factor of $g$, which is like the equation $g  = 0 \mod a$ in the CRT.
- Then, instead of looking at the individual $p_i$, we look at all the prime factors of all $p_i$ instead, which are coprime to $g$. And we need to take the prime powers of those factors into account, but it's quite straight forward as well.

Comment: One minor nit to this solution; if composite $p$'s are allowed, well, most composites don't have generators (in the sense that there is no value $g$ where $g^r \bmod p$ takes on all values relatively prime to $p$)